# VBA-Object Required Error

Tags: excel, vba

I was writing a function with ws declared already. It works well under the private sub of the command button but when i extract it as a function it shows the object required error. The file is too large and I must make it as a function and call it but the error stopped my program running.
Could anyone please help me thanks a lot.

```
If Month(ws.Cells(j, 11)) = "a" And Year(ws.Cells(j, 11)) =  ComboBox1.Text Then  'this sentence error


If ws.Cells(j, 5) <> "-" Then     'this sentence also error if I deleted the above one
n = 2
Else: n = 1
End If
p = 1
```

Comment: Your post doesn't show the source of the error. Try to post a complete procedure so that we can see how the `Ws` and `ComboBox` objects become available. The location of the code is also important as is the location of the ComboBox (on a sheet or in a UserForm)

Comment: And how do you expect `Month(ws.Cells(j, 11))` (which, assuming the cell contains a date, will return a number between 1 and 12) to be equal to the string `"a"`

Comment: These codes are in a function named procedures written below my macro. I have set ws and ComboBox already in the macro. For    a, i set that as the parameter of my function procedures as Function Procedures(a as integer).